# How to get favicon's URL from a generic webpage?

Tags: php

I need a way to get the favicon's URL from a generic webpage considering that the favicon is not always at the base url.

P.s. without using an external service.

Comment: Hi Robot, if you are able to ask question at SO, you are definitely able to download favicons, aren't you :-)

Comment: yep, but I have to do that in PHP :D

Comment: http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 7):

A page's favicon is always either at

- The root of the domain, then /favicon.ico (http://example.com/favicon.ico)
- or the URI pointed to by a "shortcut icon" <link> tag.

Try a HEAD request for /favicon.ico first (CURL should be able to do that), if that doesn't work, fetch the page itself, parse the HTML and see if you can find a matching tag.

Comment: I think a regular expression should be enough to extract the meta tag, without parsing the whole file

Comment: @pomeh A regex, even for something like this, is hard to get right. Jeff Atwood talks about this here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: well.. That's right, but I think it's not *that* complicated in this case, something like this would work no ? `/<link\s+(?:rel="(?:shortcut\s+)?icon"\s*)?href="([^"]+)"(?:\s*rel="(?:shortcut\s+)?icon"\s*)?\s*/?>/`

Comment: @pomeh Your regex fails to match when the rel and href attributes are reversed, and also fails when a type attribute is added, which is recommended. Your regex, therefore, will not work on sites that play by the rules, let alone sites that don't.

Comment: `/<link\s+(?:type="[^"]+"\s*)?(?:rel="(?:shortcut\s+)?icon"\s*)?(?:type="[^"]+"\s*)?href="([^"]+)"(?:type="[^"]+"\s*)?(?:\s*rel="(?:shortcut\‌​s+)?icon"\s*)?(?:type="[^"]+"\s*)?\s*/?>/` ? While it should works, I get your point, this regex is horrific :)

Comment: @pomeh HTML 'in the wild' can *not* be parsed with a regex. Even this monstrosity fails when arguments are in a different order or if the site uses single quotes instead of double quotes (which has been perfectly valid for decades). I would, with all due respect, recommend you to stop trying.

Comment: Yep I get your point :) But for your information, this one doesn't fail about attributes order

Comment: @pomeh It does. Try moving the type attribute.

Comment: **Never use `Regex` to parse HTML strings!**

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to both get the contents and parse the results:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

$icon = '';
foreach($html->find('link') as $element) {
    if($element->rel == "shortcut icon" || $element->rel == "icon")
        $icon = $element->href;
}
```

Note: The code above only gets icons if they are specified in a `link` element

Comment: It doesn't return the href value if defined rel value is in uppercase. How can that be resolved?

Comment: try setting a variable, ie, `$rel` equal to the lower-cased version, something like `$rel = strtolower($element->rel)` and using that inside the condition of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an HTML parser to look for link tags that include favicon information.  The type attribute should be set as "image/x-icon" and the rel attribute is either "shortcut icon" or "icon".  The href attribute will be the address of the favicon.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `S2 service`
 provided by google. It is as simple as this

```
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score -2):

For future use, to get the favicon of a page using jQuery you can use

```
jQuery('link[rel*=icon]').attr('href');
```